# Python nested defaultdict issue

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I’m trying to populate a nested defaultdict and change the `default_factory` of some of the inner dicts after initialisation.

```
dictA=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
```

After populating and doing some calculations I now want to change the default value:

```
dictA[‘a’].default_factory = 1.0
dictA[‘b’].default_factory = 2.0
```

For some reason `dictA[‘a’]` now also changed it’s `default_factory` to 2.0. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Some of my actual code:
I load text from a file to populate the ngram.

```
ngram = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))

##Filling the dictionary

for hist, next_words in ngram.items():
    hist_occ = sum(value for word, value in next_words.items())
    V = len(next_words.items())
    if (k!=0):
        ngram[hist].default_factory = lambda: float(k / (hist_occ+ k*V))
```

When I check the values afterwards, all of them seem to be equal to he last calculated value

Comment: You should not use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example, in my code it has a different name

Comment: Not able to reproduce your example, I'm getting 1.0 for `dictA[‘a’].default_factory`. Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: I added some of my code